# Android - Create a ribbon on top of a row of a Recycler View?

Tags: android

As shown in the below image, I want to create a Recyclerview with each row/ card view showing "Sale" in a ribbon style wrapped over the row. I have already created the recyclerview and populated the data. Only the "Sale" ribbon is not coming.

How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: try `View#setForeground(Drawable foreground)`

Comment: Why is this question getting so many downvotes? I think this is absolutely a programming question. If this is not a programming question, how can someone do it in Android.?

Comment: How did you solved this issue? I have the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150345/how-to-override-standart-padding-in-cardview-while-using-cardusecompatpadding

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RelativeLayout` for this task.

Put your card's content into a `LinearLayout` (call contentView this time) and give it some `layout_margin`. Then put this content view into a `RelativeLayout` and add the sale ribbon as an `ImageView` child element.
Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@color/white">
        __content_of_the_card__
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ribbon"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```