# How to override standart padding in CardView while using cardUseCompatPadding?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

When I use cardUseCompatPadding to show shadow in my card view, top padding is bigger than left one. How to make both padding equal, because my ribbon looking not beautiful, it's bigger on top? Thanks.

[image]

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- Green triangles for badge -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ribbon_parts"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_ribbon_parts"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/item_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:theme="@style/LightGrayHighlightTheme"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:weightSum="3"> </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<!-- badge -->
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ribbon_main"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_ribbon_main"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

https://www.shutterstock.com/search/new+blue+corner+ribbon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from the documentation:

> This may cause Cards to have different sizes between Lollipop and
>   before Lollipop. If you need to align CardView with other Views, you
>   may need api version specific dimension resources to account for the
>   changes. As an alternative, you can set this flag to true and CardView
>   will add the same padding values on platforms Lollipop and after.

Next, you can add the indentation you need by using the *margin* attribute

**example.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2861">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/item_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <!-- Your code here -->

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- badge -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ribbon_main"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@drawable/corner_ribbon"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now it looks great on different versions of the API.

[API 19 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvCyc.png)

[API 26 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPCX8.png)

[comparison side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPPoS.png)

In your project, you can use these settings for both CardView and FrameLayout (ribbon) to achieve the desired result.

**example_2.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2861">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/item_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <!-- Your code here -->

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- badge -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ribbon_main"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/corner_ribbon"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[increased indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2QnN.png)

Comment: Why are you using different margins from top,bottom/left,right?

Comment: In fact, in my example, only two margins are important: layout_marginEnd, layout_marginTop. (layout_marginBottom and layout_marginStart are used for symmetry). They are necessary so that the edges of the CardView coincide with the edges of the FrameLayout (ribbon). In your project, you can use these settings for both CardView and FrameLayout (ribbon).

Answer (score 2):

You can't fix this. When `cardUseCompatPadding` flag is set, these methods are used to calculate padding on all API levels:

```
final static float SHADOW_MULTIPLIER = 1.5f;

static float calculateVerticalPadding(float maxShadowSize, float cornerRadius, addPaddingForCorners) {
   if (addPaddingForCorners) {
      return (float) (maxShadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER + (1 - COS_45) * cornerRadius);
   } else {
      return maxShadowSize * SHADOW_MULTIPLIER;
   }
}

static float calculateHorizontalPadding(float maxShadowSize, float cornerRadius, boolean addPaddingForCorners) {
   if (addPaddingForCorners) {
      return (float) (maxShadowSize + (1 - COS_45) * cornerRadius);
   } else {
      return maxShadowSize;
   }
}
```

`addPaddingForCorners` is true when you use `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"`.

Perhaps setting some `layout_marginTop` on `ribbon_main` and `ribbon_parts` will give you the desired effect?

Comment: so doesn't that mean that vertical padding is always _multiplier_ times greater than horizontal padding.... can't he just subclass the CardView and override that method? opinions !?

Comment: yes, vertical padding is always greater because of the multiplier. he can't because these methods are static and belong to a package-private class

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me, may be it would work for you too:

```
    float cardelevation = cardView.getMaxCardElevation();
    float cardradius = cardView.getRadius();
    double cardcos = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(45));

    int horizontalPadding = (int) (cardelevation + (1 - cardcos ) * cardradius);
    int verticalPadding = (int) (cardelevation * 1.5 + (1 - cardcos ) * cardradius);
```

Thank You.

Comment: but it's just code from the inner support library, where to apply it in my xml or code exactly?